# Rails split string value as group of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, save, polymorphism

I currently receive from a form a string who looks like that :

```
one tag,another tag,yet another
```

Inside my Rails app I implemented a polymorphic association :taggable in order to manage tag (taxonomy) on my system. What I want now is to save those value in the database with of course, the less code as possible. My tables structure looks like that :

```
// Assocition table
TermRelationship(id: integer, taggable_id: integer, taggable_type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

// Term table (tag)
Term(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, type: string)

// Blog table
Blog(id: integer, title: string, body: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

So far what I did is to split those value as an array :

```
tags = params[:blog][:tag].split(/,/)
```

Now the only I can think of is to have a loop in order to add one by one each value. But Im sure there is another "Rails/Ruby"-like to do it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Take a look at https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I wanted to do it that way for a learning purpose since I just start with Rails. Will do it later then because I want to know how it works under the hood. Anyway, thanks again